# Is it possible to guard the entirety of an Angular app?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing

I have my application set up where many of my components are protected. However, the user is still able to access the main page "/". I was wondering if it would be possible to redirect the user to /login if they are not authenticated without making ALL of my components children of whatever component I have on "/". I'll include a modified version of what I have below:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "login",
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: "test",
    component: TestComponent
  },
  {
    path: "protected",
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    component: ProtectedComponent
  },
  {
    path: "alsoprotected/:id",
    component: AlsoProtectedComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    children: [
      { path: "child1", component: ChildOneComponent},
      { path: "child2", component: ChildTwoComponent},
      { path: "child3", component: ChildThreeComponent },
      { path: "child4", component: ChildFourComponent },
      { path: "child5", component: ChildFiveComponent },
      { path: "child6", component: ChildSixComponent },
      { path: "child7", component: ChildSevenComponent }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: "protectedsettings",
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    component: SettingsComponent
  }
];
```

Is there some way to add my GuardService to my app-root component?

Comment: @JonasLochmann This is true but, it is always good to try and make your users aware when they can't do anything because they're not authenticated. At least imo. To that end it's usually good to have front and back end security.

Comment: Are you asking about redirecting routes? https://angular.io/guide/router#redirecting-routes

Comment: This may be a valid feature request, it's probably a nice UX feature in some applications. But the security tag should be removed, because this has nothing to do with security, and will have zero effect on the security of the application (if not a false sense of security). :)

Comment: Consider it done.

Comment: @Eliseo yes I am specifically this portion of that guide. https://angular.io/guide/router#canload-guard-guarding-unauthorized-loading-of-feature-modules. My whole app requires the user to be authenticated to do anything so I want to always redirect them to /login if they are not logged in not just set of admin components.

Comment: by root, do you mean the root url `/` or root component? If you need to guard any component, create conditions in your `ngOnInit` method to reroute the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a componentless route in the same level as login and move everything other than login inside that route. Then add the guard to that route.

```
        const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: "login",
        component: LoginComponent
      },
      {
        path: "",
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
        children: [
          {
            path: "test",
            component: TestComponent
          },
          {
            path: "protected",
            canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
            component: ProtectedComponent
          },
          {
            path: "alsoprotected/:id",
            component: AlsoProtectedComponent,
            canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
            children: [
              {path: "child1", component: ChildOneComponent},
              {path: "child2", component: ChildTwoComponent},
              {path: "child3", component: ChildThreeComponent},
              {path: "child4", component: ChildFourComponent},
              {path: "child5", component: ChildFiveComponent},
              {path: "child6", component: ChildSixComponent},
              {path: "child7", component: ChildSevenComponent}
            ]
          },
          {
            path: "protectedsettings",
            canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
            component: SettingsComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
```

check this [link](http://vsavkin.tumblr.com/post/146722301646/angular-router-empty-paths-componentless-routes) for more info

Comment: I wanted to add that this is a valid solution but, as in the question I didn't want to make all my components children of a main wrapper component simply for authentication.

Comment: componentless route means route without component. This is exactly what you should use when you don't want a wrapper component.

Answer (score 3):

Inside your app root component in the constructor you could use the router to catch the instance `NavigationStart` from the router.

```
export class AppComponent {

    constructor(private router: Router) {

        router.events.subscribe( (event: Event) => {

            if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
                //Check either LocalStorage or cookies for value
                  if(!localStorage.GetItem('hasLoaded')){
                     this.router.navigate['./login']
                  }

            }

        });

    }
}
```

Another option is a CanDeactiveRoute in your routing file

```
import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable }    from 'rxjs';

export interface CanComponentDeactivate {
 canDeactivate: () => Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
}

@Injectable()
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate> {
  canDeactivate(component: CanComponentDeactivate) {
    return component.canDeactivate ? component.canDeactivate() : true;
  }
}
```

Using this check alongside localStorage is a good start, you could use something like server side sessions and a `HTTP Interceptor` alongside this also.

---

**Be advised the user can disable this and it's not meant to obscure or hide sensitive data. Do that on a server using secure transmission mechanisms, you've been warned.**

Comment: I tried your first solution and it worked exactly as I imagined. Thanks! Rest assured all back end calls are secured so no data is displayed without validation :)