# CanActivateFn get hit but same appcomponent get hit too. standalone. angular

Tags: angular, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

My environment as ng 17.1.13, node 19.9.0, npm 9.6.3. Standalone application.

My app.routes.ts

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { authGuard } from './guard/auth.guard';
   
export const routes: Routes = [
    { 
        path: '',
        component: AppComponent,
        pathMatch : 'full',
        canActivate: [authGuard],
    },]
```

auth.guard.ts

```
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivateFn, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { TokenService } from '../services/token.service';

export const authGuard: CanActivateFn = (route, state) => {
    const tokenService: TokenService = inject(TokenService);
    const router: Router = inject(Router);

    return false;//breakpoint hit
   // return tokenService.isAuthenticated();
};
```

app.config.ts

```
import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { provideHttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { routes } from './app.routes';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
    providers: [provideRouter(routes), provideHttpClient()]
};
```

app.component.ts(code snippet)

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, OnInit, EventEmitter,    Inject,
 } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators, ReactiveFormsModule, ValidationErrors  } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
     selector: 'app-root',
     standalone: true,
     imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, ReactiveFormsModule],
     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrl: './app.component.css',
     encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
   })
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

async ngOnInit() {
   this.buildForm();
   }

buildForm(){
    this.surveyForm = new FormGroup({//breakpoint hit
 });
}
```

As authguard returns false, I'd expect appcomponent no chance to run? but they run anyway.

Comment: AppComponent is the entry point to the app.  You can't guard this.  Make another component and then associate this to whichever route you want to guard.  Do not try and guard the AppComponent.  Also, your goal appears similar to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51178052/is-it-possible-to-guard-the-entirety-of-an-angular-app

If this helps, upvote the comment, and I will distill to an answer.

Comment: @AdamCox Thank you. I don't know how to upvote the comment :)

Comment: @AdamCox please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78083540/angular-router-navigate-show-error-page-standalone-ngoninit .   Thanks!